# Set file ownership to www-data in Windows

Tags: file-permissions

I am using FileZilla to upload a file to a server but it needs to have the owner **www-data**. I can't change it once it is uploaded. Is there any way I can change it on my side before uploading? Or better still changing the ownership of all folder/files for the local instance.

I have looked at setting it here but **www-data** does not appear to be a valid input.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The owner of a file has to be a user that exists on the system the file is on.

The *www-user* user exists on the server (which will run some flavour of UNIX since that is a traditional username for the account which runs the HTTP server).

The *www-user* does not exist on your desktop computer.

Even if your organisation used a centralised user database (like Active Directory), it is unlikely it would be set up in such a way that the *www-user* on the server was available through it.

---

Generally, if you want to upload a file using FTP that should be owned by a particular user, then you should log into the FTP server with that user account.

Answer (score 0):

The owner is controlled by the remote end. You need to see if FileZilla can persuade the FTP server to change it. This can sometimes be done by logging in to the FTP server as that user.

With a command-line FTP client, and if the server supports it (most don't), `SITE EXEC chown www-data myfile` might work.